# Can't setup SSH server on Cygwin

Tags: ssh, cygwin, openssh, sshd

I had set this up a while ago on a different computer, but I can't get it running now. I've followed the directions at http://pigtail.net/LRP/printsrv/cygwin-sshd.html and I'm getting the following error.

```
Gulshan@GSJK-PC ~
$ cygrunsrv -S sshd
cygrunsrv: Error starting a service: StartService:  Win32 error 1069:
The service did not start due to a logon failure.
```

I don't know where to start troubleshooting this error... I've ran Cygwin with admin privileges every time I installed it and when I run the cygrunsrv or net start commands.

net start sshd doesn't work either.

Comment: What version of windows are you running now and what version of windows where you running when it worked?

Comment: @Nifle Windows 7 now, and I believe XP worked.

Comment: I have no real insight but have you tried starting the cygwin shell as administrator?

Comment: @Yes, that was included in the question.

Comment: No, you said that you ran as administrator when you installed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `ssh-host-config` command in a Cygwin shell.  That sets up the privsep user, and the host keys, etc.   I just set Cygwin ssh up on Windows 2008 R2, and once I did this, it worked for me.

Comment: Yea, I did that. It gave me a couple warnings, but they seem to be common warnings. No luck.

Comment: Did you start the server by typing `net start sshd`?  If that fails, check the server log in `/var/log/sshd.log`.  I've found helpful error messages in there.